# Sum of two rows from result table mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, rows

I want to get sum of two rows from the result query. I have tried this code but it doesn't seem to work. But if i remove tot it worked but doesn't give total.

```
INSERT INTO totaltransportcost
    select year(date) as y, month(date) as m, sum(FuelCost) as fc, SUM(OtherExpenses) as oe, SUM(fc+as) as tot
    from turn
    group by year(date), month(date)
```

Comment: How does it now work?

Comment: it gives syntax error

Comment: Store year and month as a single entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem (at least) is that you cannot re-use aliases in the same `SELECT` where they are defined.  So:

```
INSERT INTO totaltransportcost
    select year(date) as y, month(date) as m, sum(FuelCost) as fc, 
           SUM(OtherExpenses) as oe,
           SUM(FuelCost + OtherExpenses) as tot
    from turn
    group by year(date), month(date);
```

I would also to advise you to include all the columns being inserted.  This is a good habit to get into.  So:

```
insert into totaltransportcost(y, m, fc, oe, tot)  -- or whatever the column names are
     . . .
```

Comment: is it means do i need to enter the result table names to insert them to totaltransportcost table

Comment: Column names, not table names.

Comment: Thanks sir it really helped.